# Generate Excel report with large dataset

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, report, large-data

I'm looking for the best approach to generate a Excel report with a large dataset. It is going to generate around 100k rows or more. I used to use jasper report but I have doubts if it's ok wiht this large dataset because I'm reding it's not.
It's an web app using java8, springboot and hibernate and the idea is to select some filter and generate the report clicking a button, therefore, I'd like a good performance for the user experience.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Your question is very generic.

Comment: I think you can try ```Apache POI```

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff I dont have any idea about what are the posibilities and I'd like to be suggested by experience. Do you need more details?

Comment: @Antaaaa is it ok to generate report ? or just to "export" the data into excel? I think is the second.. isn't it?

Comment: Is excel the best for this? We used SAS to generate files from 10meg of data some 180000 files...

Comment: @AntonioDiaz - You can check out the official documentation. There is a lot of stuff you can make using Apache POI. Some links:
https://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/apache-poi-generate-excel-report.html
https://dzone.com/articles/ready-to-use-way-for-easy-excel-report-creation-in